# javascript onevent element that returns the id of the element that was clicked

Tags: javascript, code.org

hey so for a apcs class im building a checkers game and for that game i need to figure out how that i can click on one of the checkers pieces then have it so it only lets you make the legal move but i cant figure out how to basically make a event listener that only listens for the pices then tells me what the id of what was clicked on was. if you can help me thank you. heres the link to what i have so far.https://studio.code.org/projects/applab/gkpXNSUgZXsseoFSvG2WvU-i1BcEGba59kHiZmoCQ9Q

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Please include all relevant code, with an explanation of what you don't understand, here on Stack Overflow; a [mre]. You likely use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to create a runnable snippet.